# update the gridview using onrowupdating method

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview

I copied most of the part from msdn. Clicking on update does nothing

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["hospital"];
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];//getting current index
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["NAME"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[0].Controls[0])).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["phone_no."] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["ADDRESS"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["HOS_ID"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            gvbind(GridView1, "select * from HOSPITAL"); //
        }
        catch(OracleException ex)
        {
            lblresult.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException nx)
        {
            lblresult.Text = nx.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Jere is the function that binds the `gridview` to the `datasource`.

```
 public void gvbind(GridView g, string sql)
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        //   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        Session["hospital"] = ds.Tables[0];

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            g.DataSource = ds;
            g.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
            g.DataSource = ds;
            g.DataBind();
            int columncount = g.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
            g.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
            g.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            g.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
            g.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
        }

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }


}
```

Here is the *asp.net* code < do i need to add edit template and itemtemplate to use this >

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="HOS_ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="phone_no." HeaderText="Phone_no." />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ADDRESS" HeaderText="address" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="HOS_ID" HeaderText="hos_id"/>
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: A lot of relevant code is missing. What does "gvbind" do? Similarly, while you populate the DataTable with the new details, you never pass this back to the database, presumably using a DataAdapter.

Comment: @akton i have edited the question with the "gvbind" function.I will be using multiple gridviews" for tables so i created a general function for binding. And i think binding function is passing the values back. please suggest edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the code fills the `DataTable` with the values from the edited row in `GridView1_RowUpdating` but then discards them when `gvbind` is called. The `DataTable` stored in `Session["hospital"]` is a copy of the data loaded from the database when the grid was last updated. Changing values it in just changes the in-memory copy, not the underlying table.

Instead, `GridView1_RowUpdating` should:

1. Open a connection to the database.
2. Populate a `DataTable` using a `DataAdapter`.
3. Find the row(s) in the `DataTable` that correspond to updated rows in the grid.
4. Copy the new values in to the appropriate row and cell in the `DataTable`.
5. Update the grid with the `DataTable`. This includes changes made by others outside of this page.
6. Write the changes back to the database.
7. Close and dispose of the connection and related objects.

Comment: as u said i used a dataAdapter to pass the new values and the code seems to work now. Thanks a ton !